# how to write sections 3.1 , 3.2 instead of 0.3.1 or 0.3.2

Tags: sectioning, numbering, thesis, classicthesis, subsection

Im writing my thesis and I have a thesis writing guide from my university but when ı compile it the sections shown as 0.1 ,0.2 and the subsections as 0.1.2 etc. . I dont want it to look like that , how to delete 0 from the top,how can I fix it. [image]
P.S: sorry for my bad english and gramer.

Comment: Presumably the class uses chapters as its first level, so use chapter instead of section, section instead of subsection etc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should show us a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: The zeros are  because you are in chapter 0, i.e., before of any chapter. The usual is  use `\chapter{}` for main titles and \section{} for subtitles in book-like classes,  or alternatively use a  document class without `\chapter`s  (e.g. `article`). If you really need a book like class look like an article, there other ways, however.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your document class resembles the basic `book` document class, it suffices to insert the instruction

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

in the preamble.

A compilable example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
\subsection{Subsection title}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title}
\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}

\end{document}
```

[image]